Custom Post Notice for Dangerous Content
Every so often, we get a piece of content on the site that suggests a dangerous course of action. It's usually about helmet use or riding in traffic. We'd like a custom post notice so that we can alert readers that the content in question offers dangerous advice.
Here's the content we'd like in the notice:

A significant portion of the Bicycles community has indicated that
this post contains content that suggests engaging in dangerous and
possibly life-threatening behavior. Exercise extreme caution in taking
action based on the content of this post.


How would this notice be triggered?  Would it be like a custom flag that any user can raise?  What makes this idea better than the traditional downvote-to-oblivion fate that most bad content is subject to?

Custom flag and ask a mod works on most SE sites.

Yup, it's a mod triggered notice. We're asking for it because we sometimes get dangerous content that isn't downvoted into oblivion. Sometimes, dangerous answers are even accepted.

I think this is a good idea

(can't find it) Post with helmet where camera/light was screwed through the foam using wood screws.  Possibly deleted completely.

But there's also questions where OP made a good choice and shows that in the accepted answer:

Can I drill into the handles of a B'Twin 100 Arctic?

That second question probably shouldn't earn a post notice - Perhaps notices should be intended for places where the accepted answer is arguably wrong.

It could also be applied to high-voted answers (say, due to HNQ) that are hard to delete but also not safe.

It sucks that the wood screw helmet question seems to have been deleted. I was trying to read it again a while back for laughs and because someone was asking me about mounting things to their helmet. Hopefully the poster is still alive and kicking…
